# Reset saved state of JSF components on ajax render

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm having some difficulties with components that seem to be maintaining their state (rendered, readonly, disabled, ... attributes).

Basically, I have a custom component (extending UIComponentBase) with one attribute: readOnly. If that is true, all children are made readonly, and if false, the component does not do anything at all. This works very well on a single page.

```
@FacesComponent(value = "xxPanel")
public class Panel extends UIComponentBase {

  @Override
  public String getFamily() {
    return "b.z.x.Panel";
  }

  @Override
  public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context) throws IOException {
    Boolean readOnly = (Boolean) getAttributes().get("readOnly");
    if (readOnly != null && readOnly) {
        processViewTree(this, readOnly);
    }
  }

  private void processViewTree(UIComponent component, boolean setTo) {
    for (UIComponent child : component.getChildren()) {
        if (EditableValueHolder.class.isAssignableFrom(child.getClass())) {
            if (child instanceof UISelectOne || child instanceof UISelectMany) {
                callMethod(child, "setDisabled", setTo);
            }

            callMethod(child, "setReadOnly", setTo);
        }

        processViewTree(child, setTo);
    }
  }

  private boolean callMethod(UIComponent component, String name, boolean setTo) {
        Method method = component.getClass().getMethod(name, boolean.class);
        method.invoke(component, setTo);
        return true;
  }
}
```

However, when I re-render the @form (or another parent compoent) with an ajax call, and here, the readOnly attribute evaluates to false, then my children do not get enabled again. So it seems like JSF is not re-evaluating the readonly property values of the components themselves in this case.

I think this is because the components retain state... but any pointer on how to resolve this issue would be very welcome!

Comment: please post some code

Comment: @MicheleMariotti : not 'some code' but a [mcve] a requested in [ask].  'Some code' is in 90% of the cases to vague to answer the problem

Comment: Something like this: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute? You can either use it or take it as an example.

Comment: Interesting differences there indeed. Will try to rewrite mine (as I need to override the component's own value always if readonly=true on my panel). Would the problem then be in me setting the attributes rather than changing the valueexpression? Or rather the diff between UIComponent vs TagHandler?

Comment: The problem is exactly because I override the property at all times. After the ajax call, I end up with the component isReadonly()== true, but when I evaluate its valueexpression for readonly, it's false... So, how do I force JSF to re-evaluate the valueexpression?